# Windows Docker container keeps restarting

Tags: windows, docker, dockerfile

I built an image using `sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019` image and when I run the container using that image, it constantly keeps restarting. Can someone please help me figure out the issue?
My container host is Windows Server 2019.
Here is my dockerfile

```
# escape=`
FROM dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019

USER ContainerAdministrator

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
### Set TLS to 1.2
RUN [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12



### Chocolatey installation
ENV chocolateyUseWindowsCompression=false
RUN Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
ENV chocolateyUseWindowsCompression=false
RUN choco config set cachelocation C:\chococache
RUN choco feature enable --name allowGlobalConfirmation 


### VS Build Tools 2017
RUN choco install microsoft-build-tools
RUN choco install visualstudio2017-workload-webbuildtools


### Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.2 Developer Pack
RUN choco install netfx-4.6.2-devpack --confirm --limit-output

### .Net Core SDK 1.0.1
RUN choco install dotnetcoresdk

### .NET Core SDK 1.1.14
RUN choco install dotnetcore-sdk --version=1.1.14

### .NET Core SDK 2.2.402
RUN choco install dotnetcore-sdk --version=2.2.402


### MVC 4
RUN choco install aspnetmvc --confirm --limit-output

### MVC 3
RUN choco install aspnetmvc --version 3.0.0.2 --confirm --limit-output

### Gitversion
RUN choco install gitversion.portable

### Node JS 9.4.0
RUN choco install nodejs --version=9.4.0

### Install grunt
RUN npm -g install grunt-cli

RUN Remove-Item -Path 'C:/Program Files/Dotnet/SDK/6.*' -Force -Recurse

USER ContainerUser

### Define the entry point for the docker container.
SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]
```

Here is my `docker build` command:

```
docker build -t net.buildagent:v1 .
```

and here id my `docker run` command:

```
docker run --name buildagent -d --restart=unless-stopped net.buildagent:v1
```

Here is what I see in `docker logs`:
[image]

No Errors in logs. I have no clue what might be wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

By default, you won't see logs from Windows containers via `docker logs`. You have to use Log Monitor to be able to get Widnows logs out of the container as Windows doesn't send logs to stdout, which is what `docker logs` checks. I have blogged about this here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/how-to-troubleshoot-applications-on-windows-containers-with-the/ba-p/3201318?WT.mc_id=modinfra-56286-viniap